# Entity Framework: Updating join tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, ado.net

I have following table setup:

- **Order** (ID)
- **Product** (ID) [where ProductID 1 and 2 already exist]
- **OrderProduct** (OrderId, ProductID) [two keys FK'ng to Order and Product tables]

And I'am trying to add a record to **Order** table assigning 2 products in to the order as follows:

```
var order = new Order();
order.Products.Add(new Product {ID=1});
order.Products.Add(new Product {ID=2});

db.SaveChanges();
```

**The problem is:** When saving the order, two Products are getting inserted in to the DB, instead of referring to the product records that already exists.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: you are creating 2 new Product objects. Can't you retrieve the objects from the database and store them in your Products list by reference?

Comment: @Haxx, thanks. Could you tell me. what is the difference between having a **referenced** products as oppose to creating a new object that containing exact **PK's** that are required to update the **FK'S**.

Comment: Because I think EF doesn't work in the fashion you expect it to. Try the answer below and see how the tables are designed in sqlserver. a product will be updated with a FK to order. I am not sure, but I think you are trying to do the opposite. Anyway, I have the exact same thing as answered below, and it works :). Hope I am not making it more confusing this way... :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use db instead of creating new Product, like in this example:

```
var order = new Order();
order.Products.Add(db.Products.First(p => p.ID = 1));
order.Products.Add(db.Products.First(p => p.ID = 2));

db.SaveChanges();
```

Or, you need to "Update Reference" after product creation. 
you can do something like this:

```
var product = new Product() { ID = 1 };
db.Attach(product);
order.Products.Add(product);
```

Comment: @RoBYCoNTeless, that fix the problem. Further If i may ask where is this **"Update Reference"** is kept, is it in EF **ObjectSet** or **ObjectContext**? As a learning point for me could you elabarate little more on this **"Reference"** aspect. Thanks.

Comment: The reference is stored inside EntityState of the object (Product in this case). The object context handle these states and is able to understand what kind of operation is necessary to do. When you use the attach method, your entity is marked as "Unchanged", this mean that, since the element was stored, data is not changed and after, when you invoke "SaveChanges", Entity Framework automatically "Find" the related object to attach. I hope this link can help you better then i've tried to do: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896271%28v=vs.90%29.aspx