# How to display and update data in datagrid from multiple tables using EF and WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, data-binding

I have following database schema.

[image: Database Schema]

Problem:I would like to retrieve data from multiple tables and display/edit it in a datagrid.

Description: I would like to get relevant data from all other tables using foreign key and display it to grid. For example there Delivery.TransporterID, now i want Transporter.TransporterName which can be navigated via TransporterID foreign key and display it along with delivery columns, same needs to be done with other foreign keys.

So user can view data and edit using the same datagrid. How to achieve this using C#,WPF database first and VS2012?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is join the tables together and grab the results from the query. Here is a relevant article on using linq to accomplish the task. [How to join tables in EF LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112183/how-to-join-tables-in-ef-linq)

Comment: I already checked table joins..but i am unsure that either i will be able to update from joined table...If that is possible, would you please tell me/point me?

Comment: The easiest way is to create a reference to the joined object and call SaveChanges on the object. relevant article. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413724/entity-framework-updating-join-tables

Comment: i created joined table and set itemssource of datagrid and i can see the grid populated. 

`var query = "myquery goes here"
var display = query.ToList();
datagrid.ItemsSource = display; '

this gave me grid with data. Now how to edit/update this grid?